# Extends locator playwright with helper functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, playwright

I want to create a class that wraps the Playwright's Locator to add some utility functions.

The behavior of the locator should be **exactly the same** as the one provided by the testing framework, aside from the added utility functions.

However, if I implement the interface I have to re-implement all the functions manually, which is something I don't want since the behavior doesn't change. What is the proper way to do it?

Here some pseudo-code of what I want to do:

```
// I know I can't extend locator since its an interface but I'm using
// extends to better deliver the concept of what I want to do
export class LocatorWrapper extends Locator { 
 constructor (...args: any[]) {
    super(args);
 }
 
 public hoverAndDoubleClick = async () => {
   // This function is just a dummy
   await this.hover();
   await this.click();
   await this.click();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about to look into direction of using `PageObject` model and inheritance?

You have base class which has abstract property `mainSelector` that is root. (It can be `string` or `Locator` as you prefer, or even you can create constructor for it)

```
export abstract class PageObject {
    mainSelector: string;

    findLocator(selector: string, options?: Parameters<Page['locator'][1]>) {
       return page.locator(selector, options);
    }

    async shouldBeVisible() {
       return this.findLocator(this.mainSelector).waitFor({state: "visible"});
    }
 
    async hoverAndDoubleClick() {
        // your method
    }

   // other methods
}
```

and then each your new `PageObject` class would just extend from it.

```js
export class TestComponent extends PageObject {
   mainSelector: '.testRoot';
}
```

so `TestComponent` could use all methods from `PageObjects`.

If you have contexts, you can adjust `PageObject` class to be context independent.

```js
export abstract class PageObject {
    constructor(public mainSelector: string, public context: Page | Frame = page) {}

    findLocator(selector: string, options?: Parameters<Page['locator']>[1]) {
       return this.context.locator(selector, options);
    }
}
```

This approach can help to easily wrap actions from Playwright and manipulate tab contexts by demand.

[Example of this approach on Puppeteer](https://github.com/wix-incubator/bubanai/blob/main/src/element/baseDrivers/elementBaseDriver.ts)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Yaroslavm. I already have a POM implemented. However, since my application is really big and has a lot of components at a certain level having the locator is more functional. But instead of calling helper functions that works on every locator I would prefer to extend the existing one. But I found a solution in between of what you did and I was searching for so still I upvoted

Answer (score 1):

### Update

After exploring the documentation I realized that is usually better to **create a custom matcher** rather than extending the locator utility.

The idea is instead of extracting information by extending the locator, we create a custom function to attach to the playwright's `expect` that does the same job. *The information below is still valid but it should be used in more specific use cases to perform actions, rather than retrieving information to evaluate*.

**[Here the documentation](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions#add-custom-matchers-using-expectextend)**

Example (verify CSS color):

###### ❌ Non-optimal approach

```js
export const extendLocator = (
  locator: Locator,
): ExtendedLocator => ({
  ...locator,
  locator: (selector, options) =>
    extendLocator(locator.locator(selector, options)),
  // Extract CSS property color
  getColor: () => locator.evaluate((element) => {
    const styles = window.getComputedStyle(element);
    return styles.getPropertyValue('color');
  });
});

const customLocator = extendLocator(page.getByTestId('my-id'))
expect(await customLocator.getColor()).toBe('red')
```

###### ✅ Optimal approach

```
import { expect } from 'playwright'
const extendedExpect = expect.extend({
  async toHaveColor(locator, expectedColor) {
    return expect(locator).toHaveCSS('color', expectedColor);
  },
});


const locator = page.getByTestId('my-id')
await expect(locator).toHaveColor('red');
```

### Old version

To obtain an extended version of the locator I created a wrapper interface and then only used the locator inside my Page Object Model.

```
// Locator extension (for complete extension scroll below)
export interface ExtendedLocator extends Locator {
  //...
}

export const extendLocator = (
  locator: Locator,
): ExtendedLocator => ({
  ...locator,
  locator: (selector, options) =>
    extendLocator(locator.locator(selector, options)),
  myUtilityFunction: () => {/* EXEC SOME CODE */}
});
```

```
// POM
const baseSelector = 'my-selector'
export class PageObjectModel {
  private _locator: ExtendedLocator

  public constructor(page: Page){
    this._locator = extendLocator(page.locator(baseSelector))
  }

  public locator = (
   ...args: Parameters<Locator['locator']>
  ) => this._locator.locator(...args);

}
```

```
// USAGE
test('Should verify a condition', () => {
  // get the page from playwright

  const page = new PageObjectModel(playwrightPage);
  await page.locator('another-selector').myUtilityFunc();
})
```

To make the creation of the POM even smoother a fixture can be used. I leave the link to the docs:

- [Fixture](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-fixtures)
- [Page Object Model](https://playwright.dev/docs/pom)

### Implementation

This is a configuration that allows to keep in track all the functions that requires to be overridden to extend the Locator plus the full implemented function

```
// This will raise an error if a function that returns a locator
// is not implemented
type ExtendedLocator = {
  [key in keyof Locator]: Locator[key] extends (
    ...args: Parameters<Locator[key]>
  ) => Locator
    ? (...args: Parameters<Locator[key]>) => ExtendedLocator
    : Locator[key];
} & {
  myUtilityFunction: () => void;
};

export const extendLocator = (locator: Locator): ExtendedLocator => {
  return {
    // Utility functions
    myUtilityFunction: () => {}
    // Locator plus overridden functions
    ...locator,
    getByTestId: (...args) => extendLocator(locator.getByTestId(...args)),
    // Other functions...
  };
};
```

It is important to note that this might require maintenance if new locators are added by the API. However, typescript will raise an error, and adding them is simple: it is enough to add `newFunction: (...args) => extendLocator(locator.newFunction(...args))`.

Also to give precedence to the original API's code I suggest putting utility functions before the locator's spreading. In this way conflicts that match the original API's new feature will be overridden.